# What is the Kotlin equivalent of the Java function .asBytes()?

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the Kotlin equivalent of `.asBytes()`Java?
I am confused if `.asBytes()` in Java simply does the same function when used in Kotlin. If so, what is the purpose of `.toByteArray()` in Kotlin - if they both produce the same results?

Comment: More consistent naming maybe.

Comment: `.asBytes()` returns a `byte[]` array. Kotlin version returns a [ByteArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-byte-array.html) object, which is... a collection of bytes :) In the end both are likely either interchangeable or can be cast back and forth (or converted) since ultimately, they are just a list of bytes. :)

Comment: Do you mean `getBytes()`? @MartinMarconcini Java `byte[]` and Kotlin `ByteArray` are the same class. As for the question, this is probably for naming consistency. In Kotlin, `get` functions are interpreted as properties, but typically properties don't generate a possibly large object each time you access them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent is `toByteArray()` which does essentially the same thing.

I'm a bit confused by your question, to clarify, there's no `asBytes()` on a Kotlin `String`.

[`toByteArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-byte-array.html) returns a [`ByteArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-byte-array/) which (for Kotlin/JVM) is actually the same type as `byte[]`.

The naming difference just stems from what the Kotlin designers chose to be more idiomatic for Kotlin itself.

---

Related documentation:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#primitive-type-arrays

Comment: Kotlin has different "backends" (Multiplatform, JS) being two others I can think of.

Comment: @Michael I meant `Kotlin/JVM` as opposed to `Kotlin/JS` and `Kotlin/Native`

Comment: lol, this is like real-time stack overflow chatting.

Comment: Well if we're nitpicking, Kotlin/Android is theoretically it's own backend as well (but pretty much equivalent to Kotlin/JVM) :)

Comment: Nitpick further, everything resolves to electrons moving around :p